# ARToolKit 6: Image Tracking using FREAK

Tags: augmented-reality, artoolkit, android-augmented-reality

I am completely new to AR and I have searched all my best in Internet to get some sample on ARToolKit 6 (Android) without any success. At this point, the questions I have are

1. How do I generate an image tracker database with ARToolKit 6?
2. How do I create an Image set (with FREAK - Retina Key points or Harris
   Corners) and store in database? In ARToolKit 5.3 we used to create iset, 
   fset and then dat file. But I guess with 6 version we wont be needing 
   those.But I am not sure how to create those image sets and store in 
   database. I couldn't find any samples.

Hope someone could shed some light here :) Would highly appreciate if you could point me to some samples.
Thanks

Comment: Actually, you can use any .jpg file directly with ARToolKit6. No need to create a database. What would you need a database for? How many image would you like to track?

Comment: What if the OP wants to track a large number of images?